# Nesting of HTML Forms in one table element

Tags: html, forms, html-table

I wish to nest two separate forms within a table:

```
<form action="action1">
<table>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" ....></td>
<td>Tag1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" ....></td>
<td>Tag2</td>
</tr>
.
.
.
</table>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now for each row, I wish to add a button which would land on a different page called action2. All that action2 requires is to know corresponding to which tag (eg., Tag1, Tag2, ....) was the button clicked.

I was thinking of adding the following element in each row.

```
<td><form action="action2"><input type="hidden" name="tag_" value="corresponding_tag_in_this_row" /><input type="submit"></form></td>
```

I am generating the table programmatically but when I added this new column, I noticed that nesting of FORM elements in HTML is not allowed. What would be a good alternative to solve this?

action1 requires all the data from the checkboxes and the action2 just needs to know the corresponding tag of the row. action2 and action1 may get each others data, i.e., even if action1 gets data corresponding to both action1 and action2, it is programmed to leave out data for action2 and vice versa.

I do not wish to use any JavaScript. Suggestions for pure HTML would be highly appreciated so that there are no browser compatibility issues.

Comment: I think you can use javascript or jquery to submit form depending on which button was clicked

Comment: What exactly are the two different forms doing? I ask because this seems like it could be solved without javascript by focusing on the intent of the site.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr : The first one prints all the tags for which the checkboxes were checked and the second one just prints the tag corresponding to the button which was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a form `submit` to different actions. You either have to use JavaScript and make each button open a different page or make different forms which submit to different pages. E.g. If you want to make `button1` to submit to `page1` and `button2` to submit to `page2` you should put each one inside different forms with different `action` properties.

An example using pure javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendForm(action) {
         MyForm.action = action;
         MyForm.submit();
    }
    ButtonOne.addEventListener(
        'click', 
        function() { sendForm('action_one.php') }, 
        false);
    ButtonTwo.addEventListener(
        'click', 
        function() { sendForm('action_two.php') }, 
        false);
    ButtonThree.addEventListener(
        'click', 
        function() { sendForm('action_three.php') }, 
        false);
</script>
```

And later in your code:

```
<form id="MyForm">
    <input …/>
    …
    <button id="ButtonOne" />
    <button id="ButtonTwo" />
    <button id="ButtonThree" />
</form>
```

Comment: How should I do it using javascript? Will it work on all possible browsers? Something like this in the new column?
`<input type="button" action="/action2" />`

But how do I pass the tag corresponding to which the button was clikced?

Comment: You can make buttons submit to different actions. [See my answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71144909/215552).

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

> action1 requires all the data from the checkboxes and the action2 just needs to know the corresponding tag of the row.

You don't need a form for `action2`. Instead use a simple `a` link and construct the appropriate URL programmatically.

For example:

```
<td><a href="action2?tag={corresponding_tag_in_this_row}">Do Action 2</a></td>
```

Where `{corresponding_tag_in_this_row}` is replaced by what ever langauge or templating language you are using with the appropriate tag for that row. Given that you need this to just

> [print] the tag corresponding to the button which was clicked

This should do that without any issues, will reduce the amount of HTML required, and allow a user to bookmark that specific tag.

Comment: I need to use POST to transfer the data.

Comment: @ibp73 Why POST and not GET?

Comment: Because I do not want others to just modify the URL and do something completely different.

Comment: Using POST won't stop that. You can easily edit the HTML to send any post value. Or just CURL any URL. Using POST won't offer *any* security.

Comment: I just realized that. Why do people use POST anyway? To hide the params from the URL. Right?

Comment: Wrong. POST allows you to send extra data that a URL can't. But mostly POST is used to send and store or change data on a server. GET is used to retrieve a resource from a server. Much like GETting a page for a tag. Here's a link that might help explain it: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

HTML allows you to target different actions in buttons. The [`formaction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit#formaction) attribute can be set to a different action than the parent `form` element. I've linked to the MDN for attributes on the `input type="submit"` element, but it can be used for `button type="submit"` elements as well. So your HTML should be able to be something like:

```html
<td><input formaction="action2" type="submit"></td>
```

This will submit the entire form to that action URL however, so it will be up to you to determine how to use the information differently, on the server-side.

HTML does not allow for nesting of `form` elements, however.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your language of choice you could just have it all in one form, posting to the same file, then in that file do something based on which button was pressed.

For example in php you can do something like:

```
<form action="processing.php" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="action1" value="Do Action 1" id="action1Button">
    <input type="submit" name="action2" value="Do Action 2" id="action2Button">
</form>
```

Then in the processing.php:

```
    if (!empty($_POST['action1'])) {
    // DO ACTION 1 STUFF
    // Only look for the inputs etc that relate to action 1

    }
    // could be an if/else if there are only 2
    if (!empty($_POST['action2'])) {
    // DO ACTION 2 STUFF
    // Only look for the inputs etc that relate to action 2
    }
```

Comment: The problem here will be that we will be posting the entire form data.

Comment: True, but quoted from original post: "_action2 and action1 may get each others data, i.e., even if action1 gets data corresponding to both action1 and action2_ " so doesn't look like that is an issue.

Comment: @Jake is right. But action1 has already been defined and is running on a different server out of my reach. I have the liberty to define just action2 which is to be added now.

Answer (score -1):

follow these steps:
1.submit the results into the action page using a method(like post)
2.then specify the header location and redirect into the specified page using if.... else... clause as follows:

```
if($_POST['ACTION1'])
{
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
}
elseif($_POST['ACTION2'])
{
header('Location: http://www.example2.com/');
}
```